# Full text search for domainname, .(dot) is seen as an space or what is happening?

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

I have an collection with full text search im searching for publishers and this is the index:
Name contains an domeinname like google.nl or yahoo.com

```
{ 
    "name" : "text", 
    "url" : "text", 
    "website.description" : "text", 
    "website.keywords" : "text", 
    "website.title" : "text"
}
```

Options:

```
{ 
    "v" : 2, 
    "name" : "Text Search", 
    "weights" : {
        "name" : 100, 
        "url" : 90, 
        "website.description" : 50, 
        "website.keywords" : 80, 
        "website.title" : 80
    }, 
    "background" : 1, 
    "ns" : "newslettercollector_development.data_publishers", 
    "default_language" : "english", 
    "language_override" : "language", 
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

If i search on google.com i dont get results, if i search "google.nl" i get a result. What is the . (dot) doing?

Comment: Are you using `$text` search? because it doesn't add up.

Comment: Yes! Its like it uses . DOT as an operator? Using php driver could it be in there?